# notification could not expand in MI redmi 4

Tags: android, push-notification

I am making a project in which I need to show custom `notifications` with image, It's working perfect in all mobile phone but in **"MI redmi note 4"**
it can't be expand.I have tried below code which is working fine in all other device except MI redmi note 4. is there any solution for that? please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notification();
    }

    private void notification() {

        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnoti);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.dec_img, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContent(contentView)
                ;

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            // Inflate and set the layout for the expanded notification view
            RemoteViews expandedView =
                    new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnoti);
            notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
        }

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationmanager.notify(1, notification);

    }
}
```

customnoti.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
            />
        <TextView
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Testing is awecome"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dec_img"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: they have their own native android amalgam which doesn't stand for all features, even facebook messenger doesn't have chat head on mi phones.

Comment: I dont think MIUI support this. But grouped notifications can be expandede with 2 finger swipe down.
http://en.miui.com/thread-283417-1-1.html

Comment: Thank you so much to reply, but Ya, while searching I have found same thing, but there is one application, in this application in MI red-mi note 4 getting default expanded notification. so I am finding the way.